# I want to split a string and insert data into SQL Server 2005 table

Tags: sql-server-2005, split

I Have 3 stored procedure parameters something like

```
@String1 varchar(100) = 'a,b,c';
@String2 Varchar(100) = '1,2,3';
@String3 Varchar(100) = 'x,y,z';
```

I need this data to be split and inserted into a table as

```
column1   column2  column3
-------  -------- ----------
  a         1         x
  b         2         y
  c         3         z
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already have one function that splits separated sting into result set (see below)

```
create function [dbo].[SplitStringToResultSet] (@value varchar(max), @separator char(1))
returns table
as return
with r as (
    select value, cast(null as varchar(max)) [x], 0 [no] from (select rtrim(cast(@value as varchar(max))) [value]) as j
    union all
    select right(value, len(value)-case charindex(@separator, value) when 0 then len(value) else charindex(@separator, value) end) [value]
    , left(r.[value], case charindex(@separator, r.value) when 0 then len(r.value) else abs(charindex(@separator, r.[value])-1) end ) [x]
    , [no] + 1 [no]
    from r where value > '')

select x [value], [no] from r where x is not null
```

Using this function you can resolve your issue, for example, like so:

```
select n1.value [column1], n2.value [column2], n3.value [column3]
from [dbo].[SplitStringToResultSet] ('a,b,c', ',') n1
join [dbo].[SplitStringToResultSet] ('1,2,3', ',') n2 on n1.[no] = n2.[no]
join [dbo].[SplitStringToResultSet] ('x,y,z', ',') n3 on n1.[no] = n3.[no]
```

Result

```
column1 column2 column3
a       1       x
b       2       y
c       3       z
```

Comment: Great Function @andrey.. but I have one query that, if I have more than 15 parameters like (a,b,c),(1,2,3) and so on also the comma separated parameters are more than 20.. then is it feasible to use this function considering performance ?

Comment: The function above is working fine but I just need your views regarding performance as I mentioned in above comment ..  Thanks

Comment: this is `TVF` function that's means that it utilize `set-based approach` (instead of `procedural approach` with the `while` loop in our case). Therefore you can use this function in any set operation like `JOIN` or `APPLY` that is quite efficient I think